# The Tangent Disc Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the tangent disc topology, $X=P\cup L$ where $P=\{(x,y):x,y\in \mathbb{R}, y>0\}$ and $L$ is the real line.Then,

1. $X$ is completely regular but not normal,
2. $X$ is separable,
3. $X$ is countably metacompact.
4. $X$ is not compact

I see all of them. But I wonder $X$ can be metrizable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: a metrizable space is paracompact and therefore normal. Also, the tangent disk space is separable but not second countable, which is impossible for a metrizable space.

Comment: Oh, I see. But it can be locally metrizable? every point in the upper half plane has a metrizable neighbourdood. In the real line, the disc tangent to $L$ can be metrizable?

Comment: Yes, because a single tangent disk has the same relative topology in the tangent disk space that it has in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: But, the tangent disc not in P. It is subspace of $P\cup L$.So, it is not the same topology with Euclidean.

Comment: @ghb: Sorry; I was thinking of a slightly different space, in which what I said actually is true. Let me think about this for a minute.

Comment: Which space did you mean?

Comment: @ghb: Yes, it is metrizable: it’s $T_3$ and second countable. // I was thinking of the space that takes a basic open nbhd of $\langle x,0\rangle$ to be the union of $\{\langle x,0\rangle\}$ and the intersection with the open upper halfplane of a Euclidean open ball around $\langle x,0\rangle$.

Comment: But I think that, the family you describe above can not be contain open subsets. any intresection of open sets need not to be open.

Comment: @ghb: I think that you must have misunderstood the topology, since every intersection of basic open sets definitely **is** open.

Comment: $U_n=(0, 1\n)$ open in the real  line .But $\bigcap U_n=\{0\}$ not open.

Comment: @ghb: No, that’s not the topology. For $\epsilon>0$ a basic open nbhd of $\langle a,0\rangle$ is $$\{\langle a,0\rangle\}\cup\{\langle x,y\rangle: y>0\text{ and }x^2+y^2<\epsilon^2\}\;.$$ The topology in the open upper halfplane is Euclidean.

Comment: it should be $\{(a,0)\}\cup {\(a,y):y>0 and a^2 + y^2 < {\epsilon}^2\}$, otherwise it not tangent to $a$.

Comment: @ghb: Of course. I was not describing the tangent disk topology. As you requested, I was describing the *other* topology, the one that I was originally thinking of by mistake.

Comment: oh sorry. Is there any special name for the topology?

Comment: @ghb: I don’t know of one, but there are so many variants that I might simply have forgotten.

Comment: @ghb: You’re very welcome.